# Is it possible to send data to a specific function in bat file from python?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I'm working right now in a .bat project. Until now, a function in the .bat calls a Python script, the .py check some data in a .c file and generate a report in a .txt file, the the .bat keeps running. But I want to show the information from the .txt in the console while running the .bat. I mean, to send the information back from the .py to the .bat. I found a way to send information from .py to .bat, but these only works opening the .bat from the beginning, and that would only interrpt the process of the function.

I made two small scripts (.bat and .py) besides the already mentioned .bat project, and they work. But this logic does not work with my main project, because in the implemented logic, the .py reopens the .bat from the beginning.

This is the logic of my both small working scripts:
The .bat script:

```
@echo off
color 2f

set arg1=%1
set Tool.Python.exe=D:\uti\programs\Python27\python.exe
set Python.File.Path=C:\Users\gml1028\Desktop\sending_args.py

if "%arg1%"=="" (
    goto openPython
    )
    echo My own interface 
    echo Press 1 for showing some numbers
    echo Press 2 for showing some letters
    echo Press 3 for showing letters and numbers
    set /p select=Select: 
    if "%select%"=="1" (
        goto showNumbers
        )
    if "%select%"=="2" (
        goto showLetters
        )
    if "%select%"=="3" (
        goto showAlphanumerics 
        )

:openPython  
call %Tool.Python.Exe% -u %Python.File.Path%
goto :eof

:end 

:showNumbers
    echo 1
    echo 2
    echo 3
    echo 4
    echo The number is %arg1%
    pause
goto :eof

:showLetters 
    echo a
    echo b
    echo c
    echo d
    echo The number is %arg1%
    pause
goto :eof

:showAlphanumerics 
    echo 1a
    echo 2b
    echo 3c
    echo 4d
    echo The number is %arg1%
    pause
goto :eof
```

The .py script:

```
import os, subprocess, random 

filepath=r'C:\Users\visgmo\Desktop'
executable = os.path.join(filepath, 'sending_args.bat')
p = subprocess.Popen([executable, str(random.randrange(0,20))])
```

In this case, I don't care if the .bat restarts because I was just trying if it worked. But I do in the main project because after calling the .py file, the .bat needs to keep running.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're making a batch script that calls a python script which calls the same batch script? Why?

Comment: The batch file is a code tester and it has several functions. One of these functions is to verify the consistency of a .c file, if everything is correct. To make this task easier I am using the .py script and writing it on a .txt file. But I would also like to show this info on the terminal too, while running the .bat just in case there are errors or inconsistencies. I came out with this idea, I don't know if it is the most efficient though.

Comment: then why not log everything from the python file to a log file and read the log file from the batch to get content?

Comment: I thought it was easier this way, to avoid creating another function in the .bat file. But I think I will take your idea. 
Thank you

Comment: I honestly do not have enough time to look at a solution for this now, else I would..but what happens when you do `start /b python script` instead of call?

Comment: It seems it works. I added an echo at the very beginning to prove if it is restarted again, and it only shows only once. I'll try this on the main project.
Thanks

Comment: ok, let me know how it turns out then.

Comment: Hi! I ended up doing it from the .bat. It worked the way you told me, but I would have needed to do some more stuff to make it work, and I found the "type" command- Thanks!

Comment: ok cool, glad you're sorted out then.